# Allow same Jenkins job to be launched only after a certain step in the pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-pipeline

I currently have a Jenkins Pipeline job that have multiple steps, and I only want a new run of this pipeline to be allow to start when the previous pipeline reach a certain point.

Ex:
My pipeline as the following stages:
A -> B -> C -> D -> E

If I start twice this pipeline I would like the second Run to be only launched when the first one reaches stage C.

Thanks

Update:

This pipeline is being launched by a Git trigger, so I want to make sure that 2 push into the repo will be handled.

Ex:

Developer A push a commit and Pipeline starts

Developer B push a commit but Pipeline from DevA still running so I want this to wait

When DevA Pipeline reaches the stage C I want to allow the Pipeline from DevB to start

Comment: Why you want do this? Maybe simpler will be if you run step A and B and next in paralel you run stages: C D and E in single pipeline?

Comment: Going to update the comment to make it more clear

Comment: Why you want run job twice?

Comment: I'm not shure how to do this using pipeline plugin. But you can create second job with steps A and B and run it from pipeline and configure second job to not allow run concurent builds. When you do it you achieve your goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `lock` step (included as part of `lockable-resources-plugin`.

Your script would look like this:

```
lock('my-resource') {
  stage('A') {...}
  stage('B') {...}
  stage('C') {...}
}
stage('D')
stage('E')
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use the "Throttle Concurrent Builds Plugin" https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Throttle+Concurrent+Builds+Plugin

Put A,B and C in one group and allow only one build job for this group

Comment: Try it :). Another option would be the https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Lockable+Resources+Plugin But i have not tried this myself

Answer (score 0):

I think that the most "official" way is to use [lockable resources plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Lockable+Resources+Plugin).(implemented as part of https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-30269)